# How to parse in linux sniffer results on the fly?

Tags: linux, sniffer, tshark

I want to sort and calculate how much clients downloaded files (3 types) from my server.

I installed `tshark` and ran followed command that should capture `GET` requests:

```
`./tshark  'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)' -R'http.request.method == "GET"'`
```

so sniffer starts to work and every second I get new row, here is a result:

```
 0.000000 144.137.136.253 -> 192.168.4.7  HTTP GET /pids/QE13_593706_0.bin HTTP/1.1
 8.330354 1.1.1.1 -> 2.2.2.2  HTTP GET /pids/QE13_302506_0.bin HTTP/1.1
 17.231572 1.1.1.2 -> 2.2.2.2  HTTP GET /pids/QE13_382506_0.bin HTTP/1.0
 18.906712 1.1.1.3 -> 2.2.2.2  HTTP GET /pids/QE13_182406_0.bin HTTP/1.1
 19.485199 1.1.1.4 -> 2.2.2.2  HTTP GET /pids/QE13_302006_0.bin HTTP/1.1
 21.618113 1.1.1.5 -> 2.2.2.2  HTTP GET /pids/QE13_312106_0.bin HTTP/1.1
 30.951197 1.1.1.6 -> 2.2.2.2  HTTP GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1
 31.056364 1.1.1.7 -> 2.2.2.2  HTTP GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1
 37.578005 1.1.1.8 -> 2.2.2.2  HTTP GET /pids/QE13_332006_0.bin HTTP/1.1
 40.132006 1.1.1.9 -> 2.2.2.2  HTTP GET /pids/PE_332006.bin HTTP/1.1
 40.407742 1.1.2.1 -> 2.2.2.2  HTTP GET /pids/QE13_452906_0.bin HTTP/1.1
```

what I need to do to store results type and count like `/pids/*****.bin` in to other file.
Im not strong in linux but sure it can be done with 1-3 rows of script.

Maybe with `awk` but I don't know what is the technique to read result of sniffer.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just grep the log file of your webserver?

Anyway, to extract the lines of captured http traffic relative to your server files, just try with

```
./tshark  'tcp port 80 and \
           (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)' \
           -R'http.request.method == "GET"' | \
  egrep "HTTP GET /pids/.*.bin"
```

Comment: sure, i can parse logs, but sometimes i get 10-20G file size and it causes to high CPU. So I try to sniffer it

Comment: just parse the output like this `tail -f /path/logfile | grep etc` if you need the data `from now on`